# Redirect sound from one earpiece into both earpieces of a earphone

Tags: earphones

I have a fully functioning earphone, which I plug into my computer running windows 10. The audio that I am listening to has a clean sound in the left earpiece, and a noisy sound in the right one. (This is a characteristic of the audio; my earphones are functioning perfectly)

What I would like to achieve is the following:

1) Mute/Delete/Cancel the noisy sound in the right earpiece.

2) Redirect the clean sound from the left earpiece into both the earpieces.

Is it possible to do so? If not, is there another way to tackle this issue?

Comment: https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/

Comment: Thanks a lot for you comment! I want to upvote it, but I think I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: That's ok I'll pop it in an answer for you so you can do it there! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is probably something like "VOICEMETER" from VB-Audio. This can currently be found at: https://www.vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/